# access to Aurora instance via .net (c# / f#)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, amazon-web-services, f#

I have been using aws RDS to create and access databases on Amazon (aws).

I have a few Microsoft SQL instances and have been accessing them fine through .net c# and f# , using both SqlDataConnection and F# type providers methods. I’m accessing remotely not from the aws server.

I have just setup an Aurora db (MYSQL based) with “IAM” not enabled, I’m accessing the db using the mysql driver (MySql.Data.MySqlClient) also tried the SQL server one as a desperate attempt.

Connection string = 
var(let) mysql_conn_str = @"server=xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com; uid=myAuroraUsername pwd=mypassword; database=mydefaultdb"

I have tried to use both the endpoint address and the instance address of the Aurora db, no difference in error.

The instances are Publicly Accessible

I cannot seem to access the Aurora db instance via .net, I can access just fine via Talend and MySQL workbench, so connection is possible.
The error message I’m getting is:
“Access denied for user 'myAuroraUsername'@'192.168.xxx.xx' (using password: YES)”

Question: Is access to Amazon Aurora flavour of MySQL possible with the driver I’m using and if it is why is my local IP address being appended to the username I pass in my connection string?
Thanks, in anticipation.

Comment: There is no semicolon after the username in the connection string you posted. Is that the case in your code as well?

Comment: Aaron, sorry, typo, there sure is in my code.

Comment: Any way you can post the actual connection string for the C# connection exactly as is, but just mask out the identifying info?

Comment: Update: deleted Aurora Instance and setup new one, connection worked first time. Glitch ? Thanks for the assistance Aaron.

Comment: Weird. And the connection string was exactly the same except for the server parameter?

Comment: I've had no problems connecting to Amazon Aurora RDS instances with MySqlConnector; you might want to try that: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector